# Node Cloudinary Picture Upload not Working in Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, image-uploading, cloudinary

I've created a SNS web application (using node.js) where people can upload pictures (using cloudinary) into collections.
The application works perfectly on a cloud-based IDE I use for writing code; however, after pushing it to heroku, the image upload no longer works. I don't get any error message in my console, even though I think it should be console.logging it, however the error flash happens and the image doesn't upload.

Here is my code:

```js
router.post("/", middleware.isLoggedIn, upload.single('image'), function(req, res){
 cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.file.path, function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
   //if error
   console.log(err.message);
   req.flash("error", "Can't upload image, try again later.");
   return res.redirect("back");
  }
  //else
  // add cloudinary url for the image to the campground object under image property
  req.body.image = result.secure_url;
  req.body.imageId = result.public_id;
  // add author to campground
  req.body.author = {
   id: req.user._id,
   username: req.user.username
  };
```

I've tried searching other posts for a possible reason; but I can't find anything that matches my situation. If anyone can help...please, your advice would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry! The problem was the CLOUD_NAME config variable had '' marks around it.

If anyone is having similar issues, try removing the quotes around the name variable.